# discord.js how to give adjustable leveled roles - Error Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm developing a system level with discord.js and quick.db . My level system it’s a ready working but I wanna add the user to a role according them level I’m getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

That's the part of the assignment roles

````
const db = require("quick.db")
const discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new discord.Client({
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION']
});
(...)
    if(newlvl > oldlvl) 
    message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Parabéns, agora você está no Level ${newlvl}`)
    db.add(`xp_${message.author.id}_${message.guild.id}`, toadd);
    const member = message.member.guild.id;
    switch(newlvl){
      case 2: 
        member.roles.add('804505281052016681').catch(console.error);
        member.roles.remove('803707738005045269').catch(console.error);
        break;
      case 3:
        member.roles.add('804504954785628192').catch(console.error);
        member.roles.add('804505281052016681').catch(console.error);
        break; 
      (...)
        break;
      }
    ```
````

Comment: Did you check the error log? `member.roles` is `undefined`. Check out the `roles` in `message.member.guild.id`.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `const member = message.member.guild.id;` with `const member = message.member;` to obtain the member object.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.